# Deploying telegram bot on heroku [Procfile]

Tags: python, heroku, bots, telegram

Good day SO community,

I am having trouble getting my telegrm bot to work on heroku.

When doing 'git push heroku master',

i get:

remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> (none)

my Procfile contains: 'web: python bot.py'

Not sure why there is a (none) value for the types...
also when i try: heroku ps scale web=1, i get:
 No scale dynos on ⬢ pacific-dawn-42046

Also i use telebot and i dont know what to put in my requirements file. Putting telegram==1.4.3 raises an error...

Im super puzzled.. any help will be great!

Comment: Are you using any libraries? If so, what are they, what versions, and how do you install them?

Comment: can you post your code pls..

Answer (score 0):

If it is of any help, this is my requirements file for my telegram bot.

```
setuptools==18.5
pandas==0.23.4
requests==2.19.1
numpy==1.15.1
gunicorn==19.6.0
telegram-export
python-telegram-bot==8.1.1
gspread==3.1.0
oauth2client==4.1.3
psycopg2
pygsheets==2.0.0
```